# Two labeled textareas side by side with max size

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I've got two labeled textareas ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ghch4zx/)):

```html
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <label for="ta1">label 1</label>
    <textarea id="ta1">textarea 1</textarea>
    <label for="ta2">label 2</label>
    <textarea id="ta2">textarea 2</textarea>
</body>
```

These textareas should be positioned side by side, and should get as much space on the screen as they could get:

[image: layout sketch]

How can I achieve this with CSS or JavaScript?

#### Edit:

Textareas should

- positioned side by side (till width of textareas gets less than a minimum width, but this is a special case)
- automatically be resized
- grow with the width of the window
  [image: window width resize]
- grow with the height of the window
  [image: window height resize]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a CSS-only solution using `calc`, that fits my needs best ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ghch4zx/5/)):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="ta1">label 1</label>
            <textarea id="ta1">textarea 1</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="ta2">label 2</label>
            <textarea id="ta2">textarea 2</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    /* consider h1 height */
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.col {
    margin: 0 3px;
    /* consider column count (here 2) and margin (2 * 3px) */
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 6px);
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    /* only subtract margin, padding and border of textarea */
    width: calc(100% - 4px);
    /* additionally consider label */
    height: calc(100% - 20px - 8px);
    margin: 2px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid;
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another CSS-only solution using flexible box layout ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ghch4zx/6/)):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="ta1">label 1</label>
            <textarea id="ta1">textarea 1</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="ta2">label 2</label>
            <textarea id="ta2">textarea 2</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.row {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
.col {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
textarea {
    flex: 1;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid;
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/9ghch4zx/3/)

added `.col` for the `label` and `textarea` to align properly side by side and a `row` to `align-center`

```
.col{
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
}

label, textarea{
    width:100%;
}

.row {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit**

added jquery to find exact height of the body

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/oczfLk4t/1/)

```
function adjust() {

    var a = $(window).height()
    var b = $('header').height()
    var c = a - b

    $('.row').height(c)
}

adjust()

$(window).resize(function () {
    adjust()
})
```

Comment: I rewrote the description of the resize behaviour, since it was a bit misleading. The textareas themself should grow, not the space around them.